# What is the serial communication speed using TCP sockets?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am communicating using TCP sockets. One computer is using Windows commands, and the other is running on Linux using Python. The two computers are able to communicate, but I'm not sure what the bit rate is. I never set any bit rate. Is there a default bit rate? Can it be changed?

EDIT: It seems that the programs can accommodate a variety of bit rates. For example, 10 Mbps Ethernet or 100 Mbps Ethernet. I thought (wrongly) that the bit rate had to be set, as it does for serial communication over USB. It does not have to be set.

Comment: You mean bit rate. Baud rate isn't the same thing, and it doesn't have a meaning beyond the physical layer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP implements the SLOW START and CONGESTION AVOIDANCE procedures by which it tests the capacity of the underlying network and tries to exploit it, as much as possible. The process is fairly complex but, bottom line, TCP will try to use all the available bandwidth. The reference standard is the Internet Engineering Task Force rfc 5681: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5681